# "Can't open a bfd on stdout" error from gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to get the output from gcc through a pipe but it's throwing the error above. The command line is `gcc -pipe -c -o - -xc -`. The code is fed into through STDIN. Apparently, the BFD library needs a descriptor that's seekable. Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems like a strange requirement for object files.

Comment: I'm going to parse the ELF data, resolve the symbols, and run the compiled function.

Comment: Have you had a look at LLVM? There's probably easier ways to do that with it.

Answer (score 1):

Object files contain a lot of cross-references to binary offsets in various headers, and since the compiler doesn't know how large the various sections in the object file will be until it's finished writing them out, it follows that it has to go back and fill in these references after it's done writing the actual machine code. As such, most compilers will require that the object file be seekable - otherwise they would need to keep the entire file buffered in memory until they're done compiling everything!

The workaround is simply to compile to a temporary file, then `cat` this file into the rest of whatever pipeline you're trying to use this in.